# AVERAGEIF based on formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-statements

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010. I would like to do an AVERAGEIF, with the criteria based on formatting.

Ex: For cells, I choose A1-A3.

- A1 is the percentage value 10%.
- A2 is the number value 20.
- A3 is the percentage value 0%.

The result should be 10%, because A3 is 0% and A2 is a number.

Comment: But if you have two values with percentage: 10% and 0% will the average not be 10/2 = 5% ? You write "The result should be 10%"

Comment: @duDE I want it so that it will ignore 0%, but I can add that myself.

Comment: @snuggles08 shouting in Caps won't get you an answer here!

Answer (score 0):

```
AVERAGEIF( range, criteria, [average_range] )
```

According to [this article](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Averageif-Function.html) it must be possible like that (I've not tried it!):

```
=AVERAGEIF( A1-A3, "*%")
```